# Return multiple values from a function, sub or type?

Tags: function, vba, return-value, ms-word

So I was wondering, how can I return multiple values from a function, sub or type in VBA?
I've got this main sub which is supposed to collect data from several functions, but a function can only return one value it seems. So how can I return multiple ones to a sub?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You might want want to rethink the structure of you application, if you really, really want one method to return multiple values.

Either break things apart, so distinct methods return distinct values, or figure out a logical grouping and build an object to hold that data that can in turn be returned.

```
' this is the VB6/VBA equivalent of a struct
' data, no methods
Private Type settings
    root As String
    path As String
    name_first As String
    name_last As String
    overwrite_prompt As Boolean
End Type


Public Sub Main()

    Dim mySettings As settings
    mySettings = getSettings()


End Sub

' if you want this to be public, you're better off with a class instead of a User-Defined-Type (UDT)
Private Function getSettings() As settings

    Dim sets As settings

    With sets ' retrieve values here
        .root = "foo"
        .path = "bar"
        .name_first = "Don"
        .name_last = "Knuth"
        .overwrite_prompt = False
    End With

    ' return a single struct, vb6/vba-style
    getSettings = sets

End Function
```

Comment: I'm trying to return the values of several settings stored in an INI file. I could write one function for each of them, but I thought that creating one would be better. Or more efficient. Not sure if it would be though.

Comment: You're thinking the wrong way. A method returns one thing. Is that one thing an atomic value (32, "c:\root", true, etc), or is it an object that contains multiple values ({width: 32, path: "C:\root", promptForOverwrite: true}). You're a programmer -- you need to think about these things, and design your application accordingly.

Comment: I'm a designer and general IT-technician and I'm just trying to learn programming. VBA is because of Microsoft Office applications and there are stuff I don't know yet. The values I'm trying to return is just basic string values from an INI file. Nothing fancy or anything and they can be returned as strings as well.

Comment: Sorry, that was a poorly phrased comment. Strings or whatever, you can only return one Thing. Thing may be a single string, or it may be an object that contains multiple properties that are themselves strings. But you cannot return multiple Things.

Comment: Aha! It's getting clearer now :) Ok, so I need to create and object that contains multiple values then right? Would that mean creating a class that contain these? I'm not sure how many values I need to return, it may be just a few. But depending on how this turns out, I may need to store loads of values as well. So I should probably create a system that would cope with that.

Comment: Looking into the VBA collection classes. But don't build it until you need it. Keep it simple. My biggest problem when I began coding was trying to account for eventualities that never eventualized. I spent a lot of time trying to solve problems that weren't.

Comment: Just tried it, and it works :) Fantastic! Now I have a feeling I'm actually doing this the right way instead of some straight forward, easily collapsible way..

Comment: @KennyBones - when I said "you're a programmer -- you need to think about these things" it wasn't intended as the put-down it looks like now. You may still identify as a designer -- but once you start programming: bam! you're a programmer! You're still on SO, so sounds like it's working. Congrats!

Comment: @photonic -- it doesn't work for you. What error are you encountering?

Comment: User define type not define @MichaelPaulukonis

Comment: @Photonic - why don't you open a new issue for this? You're having a different problem -- something with the User Defined Type (UDT) declaration.

Comment: That's pretty frickin' neato!

Comment: Is this equivalent of Java/C++ enumerations?

Answer (score 25):

You could try returning a VBA Collection.

As long as you dealing with pair values, like "Version=1.31", you could store the identifier as a key ("Version") and the actual value (1.31) as the item itself.

```
Dim c As New Collection
Dim item as Variant
Dim key as String
key = "Version"
item = 1.31
c.Add item, key
'Then return c
```

Accessing the values after that it's a breeze:

```
c.Item("Version") 'Returns 1.31
or
c("Version") '.Item is the default member
```

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 18):

Ideas :

1. Use pass by reference (ByRef)
2. Build a User Defined Type to hold the stuff you want to return, and return that.
3. Similar to 2 - build a class to represent the information returned, and return objects of that class...

Comment: Do you have any examples of the second idea? I think that would be what I need.

Comment: @Kenny, look at the help for the 'Type' statement. It should get you started.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use a variant array as the return result to return a sequence of arbitrary values:

```
Function f(i As Integer, s As String) As Variant()
    f = Array(i + 1, "ate my " + s, Array(1#, 2#, 3#))
End Function

Sub test()
    result = f(2, "hat")
    i1 = result(0)
    s1 = result(1)
    a1 = result(2)
End Sub
```

Ugly and bug prone because your caller needs to know what's being returned to use the result, but occasionally useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

A function returns one value, but it can "output" any number of values. A sample code:

```
Function Test (ByVal Input1 As Integer, ByVal Input2 As Integer, _
ByRef Output1 As Integer, ByRef Output2 As Integer) As Integer

  Output1 = Input1 + Input2
  Output2 = Input1 - Input2
  Test = Output1 + Output2

End Function

Sub Test2()

  Dim Ret As Integer, Input1 As Integer, Input2 As Integer, _
  Output1 As integer, Output2 As Integer
  Input1 = 1
  Input2 = 2
  Ret = Test(Input1, Input2, Output1, Output2)
  Sheet1.Range("A1") = Ret     ' 2
  Sheet1.Range("A2") = Output1 ' 3
  Sheet1.Range("A3") = Output2 '-1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

you can return 2 or more values to a function in VBA or any other visual basic stuff but you need to use the pointer method called Byref. See my example below. I will make a function to add and subtract 2 values say 5,6

```
sub Macro1
    ' now you call the function this way
    dim o1 as integer, o2 as integer
    AddSubtract 5, 6, o1, o2
    msgbox o2
    msgbox o1
end sub


function AddSubtract(a as integer, b as integer, ByRef sum as integer, ByRef dif as integer)
    sum = a + b
    dif = b - 1
end function
```

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but if you don't use your method overlappingly you can also use global variables, defined by the Public statement at the beginning of your code, before the Subs.
You have to be cautious though, once you change a public value, it will be held throughout your code in all Subs and Functions.

Answer (score 2):

I always approach returning more than one result from a function by always returning an `ArrayList`. By using an `ArrayList` I can return only one item, consisting of many multiple values, mixing between `Strings` and `Integers`.

Once I have the `ArrayList` returned in my main sub, I simply use `ArrayList.Item(i).ToString` where `i` is the index of the value I want to return from the `ArrayList`

An example:

```
 Public Function Set_Database_Path()
        Dim Result As ArrayList = New ArrayList
        Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()


        fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
        fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        fd.RestoreDirectory = True
        fd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        fd.FilterIndex = 2
        fd.Multiselect = False


        If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim Database_Location = Path.GetFullPath(fd.FileName)

            Dim Database_Connection_Var = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & Database_Location & """"

            Result.Add(Database_Connection_Var)
            Result.Add(Database_Location)

            Return (Result)

        Else

            Return (Nothing)

        End If
    End Function
```

And then call the Function like this:

```
Private Sub Main_Load()
  Dim PathArray As ArrayList

            PathArray = Set_Database_Path()
            My.Settings.Database_Connection_String = PathArray.Item(0).ToString
            My.Settings.FilePath = PathArray.Item(1).ToString
            My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could connect all the data you need from the file to a single string, and in the excel sheet seperate it with text to column.
here is an example i did for same issue, enjoy:

```
Sub CP()
Dim ToolFile As String

Cells(3, 2).Select

For i = 0 To 5
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    ToolFile = Cells(r, 7).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveCell.Value = CP_getdatta(ToolFile)

    'seperate data by "-"
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C3"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Cells(r + 1, 2).Select
Next


End Sub

Function CP_getdatta(ToolFile As String) As String
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ToolFile, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True

    Range("A56000").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    x = CStr(ActiveCell.Value)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    While IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value) = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    Wend
    ' combine data to 1 string
    CP_getdatta = CStr(x & "-" & ActiveCell.Value)
    ActiveWindow.Close False

End Function
```