# Index or create array of defined user defined type(VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, user-defined-types

so I am looking to either index a variable that is defined in a UDT of structpairofdice or erase the memory of the static intRollNum variable later on in the code. Preferably I'd like to index the sumdice variable although I haven't been able to figure it out, help is much appreciated

```
    Option Explicit

Type structPairOfDice
    diceOne As Integer
    diceTwo As Integer
    rollNum As Integer
    sumDice As Variant
End Type

'Randomizes the dice between 1 and 6
Function RandomizeDice() As Integer
        RandomizeDice = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
End Function
Sub RollDice(structDice As structPairOfDice)
    Static intRollNum As Integer
    intRollNum = intRollNum + 1
    With structDice
        .rollNum = intRollNum
        .diceOne = RandomizeDice()
        .diceTwo = RandomizeDice()
        .sumDice = .diceOne + .diceTwo
    End With
End Sub
Sub PrintResults(structDice As structPairOfDice)
    Call RollDice(structDice)
    With structDice
        Debug.Print "Roll #: " & .rollNum
        Debug.Print "Dice: " & .diceOne & ", " & .diceTwo
        Debug.Print "Sum: "; .sumDice
    End With
End Sub
Sub Main()
    Dim structDice As structPairOfDice
    SetThePoint structDice
    'PrintResults structDice
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is attempting to do when iterating over each item in the empty collection `Rolls`, but I would recommend that you use `Option Explicit` as the first line of every code module so that you don't get caught out by typos such as `intRollNim`.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "index a variable that is defined..." Also, what is SetThePoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can check these two questions and see that you may prefer to use a `Class` rather than a UDT for this:

- [Only user-defined type defined in public object modules can be coerced when trying to call an external VBA function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046552/only-user-defined-type-defined-in-public-object-modules-can-be-coerced-when-tryi)
- [User Defined Type (UDT) as parameter in public Sub in class module (VB6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975982/user-defined-type-udt-as-parameter-in-public-sub-in-class-module-vb6)

You can code a class like this:

### clsDice

```
Option Explicit

Public diceOne As Long
Public diceTwo As Long
Public rollNum As Long
Public sumDice As Long

Public Sub RollDice()
    diceOne = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
    diceTwo = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
    sumDice = diceOne + diceTwo
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    RollDice
End Sub
```

So when you create the class, `RollDice` is called straight away and `rollNum` can be set to whatever you need as it is `Public`.

Then, in a standard module you can do this to 'play the game' and use a `Dictionary` to store the results of each throw of the dice:

### Module1

```
Option Explicit

Sub PlayGame()

    Dim objDiceDic As Object
    Dim objDice As clsDice
    Dim lngMaxRounds As Long
    Dim lngRound As Long

    ' dictionary for game simulation
    Set objDiceDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' arbitrary number of rounds
    lngMaxRounds = 10
    For lngRound = 1 To lngMaxRounds
        ' creating a new dice class does the rolls for you
        Set objDice = New clsDice
        ' set the rollNum to this round
        objDice.rollNum = lngRound
        ' add the dice object to our throw tracking dictionary
        objDiceDic.Add lngRound, objDice
    Next lngRound

    ' test the simulation output
    For lngRound = 1 To lngMaxRounds
        With objDiceDic(lngRound)
            Debug.Print "Roll #: " & .rollNum
            Debug.Print "Dice: " & .diceOne & ", " & .diceTwo
            Debug.Print "Sum: "; .sumDice
        End With
    Next lngRound

End Sub
```

So each 'round' becomes the key into the dictionary, where the value is an `clsDice` object where you have also stored the round (`rollNum`). So you can easily use the dictionary keys to access the results of a particular round e.g.

```
Debug.Print objDiceDic(4).sumDice
```